# SelectedIndex of TabControl won't change in DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, triggers, datatrigger

I have a tab control that looks like the following:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl1"
        Margin="6,42,12,6"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Test.IsStopped}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </TabControl.Style>
    <TabItem...>
    <TabItem...>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

IsStopped is a property on a viewmodel (implements INotifyPropertyChanged, etc.) Now, this all works fine, but there is a catch. I also have some code behind for things like "Next" and "Back" buttons that increment the tab index

```
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int old = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    try
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex++;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = old;
    }
}
```

If this code is called at any point, the DataTrigger no longer updates the SelectedIndex. The background still changes to Red (just there to test the binding). I understand dependency property value precedence, but this is annoying as I don't seem to have control over what is going on. What exactly *is* going on? As a bonus question, I know some debugging tricks in WPF but how could I ever begin to see why this isn't working?

**EDIT 10/8/2013 2:45 EST**

Well this is interesting...I have changed the NextButton_Click event to the following in a small attempt to emulate what happens when a tab is clicked:

```
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int old = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    try
    {
        TabItem nextItem = ((TabItem)tabControl1.Items[old + 1]);
        nextItem.IsSelected = true;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = old;
    }
}
```

and things work fine. Does anyone know if there a reason why setting the index explicitly shows the aforementioned behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Well for debugging purposes, I'd hook up a handler to the SelectionChanged event and start looking at what could possibly be different from when it is triggered by your trigger versus by your try-catch. Also x:Name your DataTrigger binding, and look at it in the code behind at runtime, and be sure that that binding is the same as you expect it to be at all times (my first suspicion was that something might be changing here).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I didn't notice anything different between the two SelectionChanged Events, though I would not surprised if I missed something.  The DataTrigger appeared to be in order as well. Messing around in SelectionChanged got me thinking and I'll edit my post with some more information in just a second.